# Code using fiona is failing when trying to dissolve polygons due to different geometries

Tags: python, python-2.x, ogr, fiona

Using fiona, I am trying to dissolve a layer with hundreds, sometimes thousands, of geometries based on a dissolve field. So, geometries with the same dissolve field value will have a unary union function done to them to keep the geometries the same but appear as only one record in the layer.

The input has a geom with the type 'MultiPolygon'. The output's geom is set as the geom of the input, so still 'MultiPolygon'. I think where the problem comes from is when the union is done, it turns the multi polygon geometry into a single polygon geometry, hence when writing it to the output it gives this error code:

fiona.errors.GeometryTypeValidationError: Record's geometry type does not match collection schema's geometry type: 'Polygon' != u'MultiPolygon'

I am unsure how to change the geom of the output to Polygon because the final output will be a MultiPolygon due to all of the different dissolve field values within the data.

I am new at this, so I hope I explained the problem clearly. Let me know if you have any clarifying questions.

This is using Python 2.7.14, MSC v.1500 32 bit
GDAL/OGR version 202400

with fiona.open(inGDB, layer= 'FISH') as input:

```
meta = input.meta
with fiona.open(outGDB, 'w', layer= 'fish_dissolved', **meta) as output:

    e = sorted(input, key=lambda k: k['properties'][dissolve_field])

    for key, group in itertools.groupby(e, key=lambda x: x['properties'][dissolve_field]):
        properties, geom = zip(*[(feature['properties'], shape(feature['geometry'])) for feature in group])

        output.write({'geometry': mapping(unary_union(geom)), 'properties': properties[0]})
```

input.close()
output.close()

fiona.errors.GeometryTypeValidationError: Record's geometry type does not match collection schema's geometry type: 'Polygon' != u'MultiPolygon'